# React-alert not showing

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a simple project and I wish to implement the react-alert API but when I run it, no elements are displayed no error messages are displayed. Checking on the console the following error are emitted:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I created a script for my alerts.

Alerts.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { withAlert } from "react-alert";

export class Alerts extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.alert.show("It works!");
  }

  render() {
    return <Fragment />;
  }
}

export default withAlert(Alerts);
```

And the implemented it in the App.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { transitions, positions, Provider as AlertProvider } from "react-alert";
import AlertTemplate from "react-alert-template-basic";

import Header from "./layout/Header";
import Dashboard from "./projects/Dashboard";
import Alerts from "./layout/Alerts";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "../store";

// ALERT OPTIONS
const alertOptions = {
  timeout: 3000,
  position: positions.TOP_CENTER,
  transitions: transitions.SCALE
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
        <Fragment>
          <Header />
          <Alerts />
          <div className="container">
            <Dashboard />
          </div>
        </Fragment>
        </AlertProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 4):

From the docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alert), the correct syntax is to use `withAlert()(Component)` (Don't forget the `()`!). So in your Alerts.js, use this instead:

```
export default withAlert()(Alerts);
```

Comment: @ FrankerZ, it works like a charm. Thank you! I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start to look to this document [document  to how to used](https://github.com/schiehll/react-alert)

```js
export default withAlert()(Alerts)
```